# What's the meaning of “we'll all be speaking Japanese”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Layton gave Nimitz an idea to meet code-breaker Rocherfort:

> Nimitz: He told me he's absolutely certain the Japs are gonna hit
>   Midway and I need to know whether or not I can believe him.
>
> Rochefort: Well, if you don't believe him, **we'll all be speaking
>   Japanese**. Or, most likely, we'll be dead.

How can American speaks Japanese?

I find this line in Midway 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen the film but I believe the implied meaning breaks down like this:

"If you don't believe him *(warning you about the impending Japanese attack, then you will take no action to defend against it, therefore it will be successful, therefore the USA will lose the war to Japan, therefore Japan will conquer the US, and therefore future generations of Americans will be forced to speak Japanese, and therefore)* we'll all be speaking Japanese."

It is a little bit of hyperbole since in modern times, victors of wars don't necessarily impose their language (Germany and Japan still speak German and Japanese, after all).

Comment: German and Japanese admirals probably did have to learn some English.